# Multiple self associations in cakePHP 2.x

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have a table called Code, the table Code is toring all my room, building and asset information and they are all linked together. I am trying to associate an asset to a room and building.

```
Code
id
code
room_id
building_id
parent_id

Site
-> Building
-> -> Room
-> - > -> Asset
```

When I perform a debug($code) in my room, I am getting all data but I am not getting the names of my building and room even though the ID exists in the row. I am trying the following self assosciation.

```
  public $belongsTo = array(
    'Room' => array(
        'className' => 'Code',
        'foreignKey' => 'room_id'
    )
);
```

The error I get is as follows;

```
 Error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'code' in field list is ambiguous
```

I've listed all code in my controller and model at http://pastebin.com/L1Qc31ZB to possibly help further.

I hope I have supplied enough information to help me with this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: _I am trying to associate an asset to a room and building._ What is an **asset**? Is it a code? Is there a building table? a site table? You should better describe your data model (i.e., the SQL tables)

Comment: I have AgRizzo, I am storing is all in the same table as a tree structure.

Comment: To best troubleshoot the problem, show the raw sql that is failing. But my guess would be your virtual field definition. Get rid of it, then see if the ambiguous error goes away.

Comment: Hey AgRizzo! you solved my issue. If you want to post a solution I can accept if you like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AgRizzo solved my solution in the comments of the original question. Looks like by creating a virtual field it can cause some joining issues.